# How to avoid overwriting if cell already has value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I'm using this script to include timestamps in my spreadsheet, but I can't make it not overwrite if the target cell already has a timestamp.

I'm using this model because it enables multiple entries at once.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(event)); //DEBUG

  var ecolumnStart = event.range.columnStart;
  var erowStart = event.range.rowStart;
  var erowEnd = event.range.rowEnd;
  var ecolumnEnd = event.range.columnEnd;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Range details - Column Start:"+ecolumnStart+", Column End:"+ecolumnEnd+", Row start:"+erowStart+", and Row End:"+erowEnd);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the sheet is "+event.source.getName()+", the range = "+event.range.getA1Notation());
  var sName = event.range.getSheet().getName();
  
  var time = new Date();
  var numRows = event.range.rowEnd -event.range.rowStart+1;

    if( event.range.columnStart == 2 && sName == 'Status') { //which column to watch on which sheet
    // loop though the number of rows
    for (var i = 0;i<numRows;i++){
      var row = event.range.rowStart+i;
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A' + row.toString()).setValue(time); //which column to put timestamp in
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the setting of value,  check if it has value.

#### Code:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sName = event.range.getSheet().getName();
  var time = new Date();
  var numRows = event.range.rowEnd - event.range.rowStart + 1;

  if (event.range.columnStart == 2 && sName == 'Status') {
    for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
      var row = event.range.rowStart + i;
      // Assign to cell to avoid redundancy
      var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A' + row.toString());
      // Write only to cell if it has blank value
      if (cell.getValue() == "") {
        cell.setValue(time);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Update the condition if non-timestamp values are expected and should still be overwritten.

#### Sample input:

[image: sample input]

#### Sample output:

[image: sample output]

Note that existing dates `1/1/2021` weren't overwritten when writing on column 2. Only blank cells were written the date today which is `2/5/2021`

#### EDIT:

If there are 2 date columns, use this code:

#### Code:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sName = event.range.getSheet().getName();
  var time = new Date();
  var numRows = event.range.rowEnd - event.range.rowStart + 1;

  // If column edited is column 3 onwards (since A and B are 'First Seen' and 'Last Update' respectively)
  if (event.range.columnStart == 3 && sName == 'Status') {
    for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
      var row = event.range.rowStart + i;
      // Assign to cell to avoid redundancy
      // First Seen
      var cell = s.getRange('A' + row.toString());
      // Last Update
      var cell2 = s.getRange('B' + row.toString());
      // If First Seen is blank, update both
      // If First Seen has date, update only column B
      if (cell.getValue() == "") {
        cell.setValue(time);
      }
      cell2.setValue(time);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Sample data:

[image: sample data]

#### Sample output:

[image: sample output]

Column A is not overwritten if it is updated since it is the first update of that row. Column B is always being updated since that is the last updated column.

Comment: This one worked like a charm!

Also, I forgot to add: One column should not overwrite, but another one should. Something like "First Seen" "Last Edited".

Comment: In that case, use 2 columns for the dates, one is first seen, and last edited is the other. At first edit, populate both. For consecutive edits, you just have to edit the last edited column part.

Comment: How can I adjust  the code to accomodate these new parameters?

Comment: You don't need to add another parameter. just add additional if statement. If the last edited cell has a date, then update the last edited column only. if blank, populate both first seen and last edited columns

Comment: I added the adjusted code. kindly check @Rhendel

Comment: Thank you very much! I still have a lot to learn. I was trying to make it work but still couldn't, this last edit saved me.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't make it work after a few tries, could you show how it's supposed to be end format?
I'm new in this..

Also, I forgot to add: One column should not overwrite, but another one should.
Something like "First Seen" "Last Edited"

Comment: I have updated my answer, kindly check the updated one. @Rhendel